# Print elements from a file as separate lines

Tags: python

I have a file `myList.txt` containing:

```
[ 'aaa' , 'bbb' , 'ccc' ]
```

I want to read the file and print each element on a separate line, so that the output appears as:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I have tried:

```
fileName = "myList.txt"

accessMode = "r"

    with open(fileName, accessMode) as elements:

        print(*elements, sep='\n')
```

but the output is:

```
[ 'aaa' , 'bbb' , 'ccc' ]
```

Comment: If you were to use `"` instead of `'` it this would be valid JSON and you could use `json.load(elements)` to read the contents of the file. So if you also write this file maybe consider switching to JSON. If you only need to read this one-time the fastest way is probably to first find all `'` and replace them with `"` (assuming you don't have escaped single quotes in values, otherwise it will be more complex) and then use `json.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

fileName = "myList.txt"
accessMode = "r"

with open(fileName, accessMode) as openedFile:
    elements = ast.literal_eval(openedFile.read())

for i, e in enumerate(elements):
    print("{}: {}".format(i, e))
```

Output:

```
0: aaa
1: bbb
2: ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this. The example below gives the desired output indicated in your question. **This is assuming your desired output is alphanumeric. If you want to include special characters or exclude numbers, you may have to modify the regex accordingly.**

```
import re

fileName = "myList.txt"
accessMode = "r"

with open(fileName, accessMode) as elements:
   contents = elements.read()
   reg = re.findall("\w*", contents)
   for i in reg:
       if i == '':
           pass
       else:
           print(i)
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Comment: The output from the above resulted in one character per line, so 'a' on one line, then 'a' on the next etc. The formatting rules for comments do not allow me to demonstrate this

Comment: `[ 'aaa' , 'bbb' , 'ccc' ]` is what you have in your question and that's exactly what i used in the answer. What do you have in your file? copy and paste a sample of what you have in "myList.txt"

Answer (score 0):

```
#open file in read mode
fl = open('myList.txt', 'r')

#create a list of lines, the entire first line becomes just one element of the list - though there are no other lines
data = fl.readlines()

#Close the file
fl.close()

#the list's index is zero as it is the first line. but here list is saved only as text. So, removing unwanted characters of the first line.
data[0] = data[0].replace(',','\n').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(' ','').replace("'","")

#open file in write mode
fl = open('myList.txt', 'w')

#write with edited data
fl.writelines(data)

#close the file to ensure saving
fl.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from ast import literal_eval


file_name = "myList.txt"

with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    my_list = literal_eval(*file)
    for element in my_list:
        print(element)
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Evaluate an expression node or a string containing only a Python
> literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
> consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, `None` and `Ellipsis`.
>
> This can be used for evaluating strings containing Python values
> without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of
> evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving
> operators or indexing.